# Vue key not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've a page with 4 times the same vue component.

In HMTL:

```
<div class="column">
    <my-comp url="http://example.com/?q=today" :unique-id="1" text="Random text"
        locale="en"
        statistics-type="count_today"
        progress-color="#DA4169"></my-comp>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <my-comp url="http://example.com/?q=yesterday" :unique-id="2" text="Random text"
        locale="en"
        statistics-type="count_yesterday"
        progress-color="#DA4169"></my-comp>
</div>
```

In my vue component data is fetched from the `url` and displayed in the component.

```
<template>
    <div :key="uniqueId">
        <!-- more HTML -->
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm using the `key` attribute to prevent the components from re-using.
Unfortunately the data from the first component always returns to the default values, when the second component loads its data.

Example after loading all the data:

*First `my-comp`:*

```
amount: 0     <- default
capacity: 0   <- default
```

*Second `my-comp`:*

```
amount: 9
capacity: 15
```

**EDIT**

```
<template>    
    <div :key="uniqueId" class="tile">
        <p class="tile-title">{{ amount }}</p>
        <p class="tile-text text-muted">{{ text }}</p>

        <div class="progress" v-if="showProgress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" 
                :aria-valuenow="progress"
                aria-valuemax="100"
                aria-valuemin="0" 
                v-bind:style="{ backgroundColor: progressColor, width: progress+'%' }">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:{
            locale: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            text: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            progressColor: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            url: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            statisticsType: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            uniqueId:{
                type: Number,
                required: true
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                amount: 0,
                total: 0,
                showProgress: true,
            }            
        },
        computed: {
            progress: function(){
                return (this.amount/this.total)*100;
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.requestStatistics();
        },
        methods: {
            requestStatistics: function(){
                self = this;
                axios.get(self.url,{
                    params: {
                        what: self.statisticsType
                    }
                }).then(function(response){                    
                    self.showData(response.data);
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
            },
            showData: function(data) {
                if(typeof(data) === 'number'){                    
                    this.amount = data;
                    this.showProgress = false;
                }else{                    
                    this.amount = data.count;
                    this.total = data.capacity;
                    this.showProgress = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Show more code, the component JS.

Comment: @acdcjunior Added code

Comment: It seems to work for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/20np4r1m6y?module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue

Comment: @acdcjunior There is a problem with the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `v-bind` instead of simple html attribute so that `:key` binding would be respected:

```
:uniqueId="1"
```